# while with all zero array in condition

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I have an array `a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];`.
I want to execute a `while` loop which performs some actions on the array `a` until all the elements in the array `a` are zero.
How should I do it?

For example:

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];

while(a contains all zero elements)
    do some operations on a  
end
```

At the end of the `while` loop the `a` should be `a=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the [`any`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) function:

```
while any(a)
  %...operations...
end
```

Comment: I have tried using any but it goes into infinite loop

Comment: @user7341333: Then that means something in `a` is still non-zero. Are you dealing with floating-point values? If so, you may end up with values in `a` that are extremely close to zero, but not *exactly* zero. Take a look at this question: [Why is 24.0000 not equal to 24.0000 in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/52738)

Comment: @user7341333 If you're getting an infinite loop, your operation is not setting all of the elements to zero. I would suggest stepping through this operation with the debugger (keeping in mind gnovice's warning about floating-point).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can mimic a 'for' loop by 'while':

```
i = length(a);
j = 1;
while j<=i
   a(1,j) = 0;
   j = j + 1;
end
```

or simply, you can do this as [gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnovice) suggests:

```
j= 1;
while any(a)
  a(j)=0;
  j = j+1;
end
```

Comment: Thankyou very much gnovice you were right a was not equating to zero in the loop